# APEX 3.2: Popup confirmation after page is submitted

Tags: oracle-apex

Working with APEX 3.2:

I want to show a confirmation popup on Page 2 when Page 1 has successfully been submitted.
Right now I can get the text from the 'Process Success Message' to appear on Page 2, but instead of the 'Process Success Message' text, I want an alert popup.  Any idea how to do that?

NOTE: I don't want to put javascript on the 'Submit' button of Page 1, because if there is a validation error, the alert popup will appear anyway every time the 'Submit' button is clicked. I just want the popup to appear only if Page 1 has successfully submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

1) Edit the page template used by Page 2.  Edit the Success Message subtemplate and put a span tag around the #SUCCESS_MESSAGE# placeholder like this:

```
<span id="successMessage">#SUCCESS_MESSAGE#</span>
```

2) Create some Javascript on Page 2 to run when the page is loaded that does this:

```
if ($x('successMessage')) alert ($x('successMessage').innerHTML);
```

The Success Message is only rendered if there is a success message to display, and so the alert will only happen when there is a success message to display also.

3) You could suppress the display of the success message on the page itself if you want by adding style="display:none" to the outer div of the Success Message subtemplate.

**NB** The template change will affect all pages that are based on it, not just Page 2, so you may need to take a copy of it first.  You could include the Javascript in the page template so that you don't need to keep adding the same on load Javascript to each page.

Comment: Ok, I am a noob when it comes to JS. Would the JS look like this to call on load? <script type="text/javascript"> function func1() { if ($x('successMessage')) alert ($x('successMessage').innerHTML);} </script> If so, where do I set the 'func1' call?

Comment: I think in Apex 3.2 you have to put the call to the function in a fields called something like "On load processing" in the page attributes.  In 4.1 you would just paste the code I gave you into the "Execute When Page Loads" attribute.